# Process to continuously delete resources

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have created a function that creates a multiprocessing.Process to continuously delete "resources" (instances from a certain class) from my application. When I kill one of these resources, it gets re-created again soon after, so at all times I am supposed to have a certain number of resources. This process is meant to run in the background during the execution of some automatic tests. The inputs to the function are a percentage of resources to be deleted, the time interval at which the resources are deleted, and a maximum duration for the process (unless stopped before) When started, the process gets all the resources (by calling the function `get_resources()`, which returns a list of resources), and selects the ones that WILL NOT be deleted (I want to make sure that at all times I will have (100-percentage)% of my resources alive), then it starts deleting the resources repeatedly (always sparing the ones selected before) until it reaches the maximum duration or until the process is stopped.

I would like to get some feedback and see if there is a better, cleaner way to do this. I am interested in knowing if this code is "safe" in the case of something failing while the process is running - I don't want to create unexpected zombie processes.

Here is the actual code:

```
def create_resource_deleting_process(
    percentage,
    interval=TIMEOUT_5SEC,
    max_duration=TIMEOUT_1MIN,
):
    """
    Creates a process that, when started,
    continuously deletes resources for a certain amount of time or until the process is stopped.

    Args:
        percentage (float): Percentage of resources to be deleted.
        interval (int): Interval that determines how often the resources will be deleted.
        max_duration (int): Maximum time that the process will be running.

    Returns:
        Process: Process that continuously deletes resources.

    Example:
        resource_deleting_process = create_resource_deleting_process(
            percentage=0.5, interval=5, max_duration=180
        )
        resource_deleting_process.start()
        ...
        resource_deleting_process.stop()
    """

    def _continuously_delete_resources(
        percentage, interval, max_duration
    ):
        initial_resources = get_resources()
        number_of_resources_to_delete = math.ceil(__x=percentage*len(initial_resources))

        # Select the resources that won't be deleted.
        surviving_resources_names = [
            resource.name
            for resource in random.sample(
                population=initial_resources, k=len(initial_resources) - number_of_resources_to_delete
            )
        ]

        end_time = time.time() + max_duration
        while time.time() < end_time:
            resources_to_delete = get_resources()
            for resource in resources_to_delete:
                if resource.name not in surviving_resources_names:
                    resources.delete()
            time.sleep(secs=interval)

    return multiprocessing.Process(
        target=_continuously_delete_resources,
        args=(
            percentage,
            interval,
            max_duration,
        ),
    )
```

Comment: Did you check that the code is working before posting it? Line `resources.delete()` refers to a non-existing name `resources`.